# Changing package name before publishing production app

Tags: android, package, publish, google-play

I've got an app published on Google Play under Alpha and Beta and now I want to upload the final APK for release, however, if it's not too much trouble I would like to change the package name.  Now, I keep reading that it's not something that should be done as in effect, it would mean re-publishing a completely new project.

However, that applies to apps that have already been 'published' - does that include apps that are only currently published to Alpha and Beta? If I change it will it cause any problems with my leaderboards etc.... will I have re-create everything from scratch?  If it's going to be a hassle, I will just publish as-is....

Comment: As long as it's not published, it shouldn't be a problem.  But once it's up on Google Play, it's rather locked in.  You will have to refactor and test the crap out of it though.

Comment: Yeah @durbnpoisn, so in my case it is on Google Play but isn't currently available to the general population, only via the Alpha and Beta testing groups, so the same is true of my situation? (would be a bit of a nightmare ?)

Comment: Oh.  Sorry.  In that case I don't know.  I've never put anything up in Beta.  Why is it so important to change the name now?

Comment: Only because it's got such a generic package name, no other reason, I wanted to include my developer name within the package name, but it's no big deal, I might just leave it be for this app!  Cheers

Comment: I say leave it alone then.  It's only a unique identifier anyway.  And no matter how generic it is, no one else can duplicate it.